# Check to see if String exists in List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: java, java-8

If I have a `List<Map<String, String>>` object such as this `tempNameMapList`:

```
0
   0 = "id" -> 101
   1 = "name" -> jonathan
1
   0 = "id" -> 102
   1 = "name" -> sam
2
   0 = "id" -> 103
   1 = "name" -> tim
```

And a `String` object such as `String name = "tim"`, how would I quickly check that it exists in `tempNameMapList`?

Comment: is it any reason why you have map rather than custom object?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz see update question. Hope it adds some clarity.

Comment: are you looking to see if JUST the value "tim" exists in the tempNameMapList or are you wanting to ensure that a map with the key "name" has a value of "tim" exists?

Comment: Ideally the latter as it is more specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution using Java 8 [`anyMatch(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
boolean exists = tempNameMapList.stream().anyMatch(map -> map.containsValue("tim"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, You can use [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) which will return `true` if it is found else `false` :

```
String name = "tim";
boolean check = tempNameMapList.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> a.values().stream())
        .anyMatch(name::equals);
```

Comment: Added keys to the question... does this change the nature of your answer?

Comment: ..No It will not

Comment: you can use lambda in `anyMatch` : `.anyMatch(name::equals)`